# Ajax Perl Catalyst FastCGI child processes not dying

Tags: ajax, perl, fastcgi, catalyst

I have an ajax application built in catalyst running through fastcgi. I am noticing that all of my ajax requests spin up another process and that process sticks around indefinitely.

Ideally I would like to have my main page stick around but the ajax pages should just stop and restart as needed.

Is this a common issue and how does one get around this.

How do I tell the server to shut down inactive processes quicker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is web server dependent (and fastcgi module dependent for apache - as there are at least 2 different fcgi modules). You haven't told us which web server etc, so I can't really answer. (But consult the documentation for your web server / fastcgi module)

An alternative approach would of course be to run the server with external fastcgi, rather than in dynamic mode, which would mean you start a fixed number of processes up-front, but then never create more or less than this number to serve requests..

Comment: I am using Apache and FastCgi